# Closed subsets of regular cardinals

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, order-topology

Let $\kappa$ be a regular cardinal, equipped with order topology, and $C\subseteq\kappa$ a closed unbounded subset.

If $\alpha<\kappa$ is another regular cardinal and a limit point of $C$, is the set $C\cap\alpha$ closed and unbounded again? In Jech, Set Theory, pag.95, it seems that this is due to the regularity of $\alpha$ (clearly, the unboundness follows from $\alpha$ being a limit point of $C$), but my question is if this obviously follows from the definition of relative topology on $\alpha\subseteq\kappa$.

How about the set $C'\cap\alpha$ (where $C'$ is the derived set of $C$, i.e. the set of all limit points of $C$)? Is it closed for the same reason?

Comment: For each $\alpha<\kappa$, $\alpha=[0,\alpha)$ is an open basic set, but I don't think it's also closed. Only if it's a successor ($\beta+1=\kappa\backslash (\alpha,\kappa)$) .

But my question is: is the regularity of $\alpha$ necessary? I think no, by the definition of relative topology: $C\subset\kappa$ is closed in $\alpha$ iff $\exists B$ closed in $\kappa$ such that $C=B\cap \alpha$

Comment: $C\cap\alpha\subseteq\alpha$ is indeed a closed subset of $\alpha$ (though, as Ajeje points out, not a closed subset of $\kappa$ (and if $C$ is unbounded in $\alpha$, then it will never be a closed subset of $\kappa$)).  This follows straightforwardly from the definition of the relative topology, in particular, note that the order topology on $\alpha$ is the same as the relative topology on $\alpha$ as a subset of $\kappa$.

Comment: The regularity of $\alpha$ makes $C\cap\alpha$ closed in $\kappa$ too: each limit point of $C\cap\alpha$ is in $C$ for closure of $C$ in $\kappa$, but it's also lower than $\alpha$ by regularity (each less-than-$\alpha$ sequence has limit below $\alpha$), so it's in $C\cap \alpha$.
\\
But Jech point out that $C\cap \alpha$ is closed in $\alpha$ because of regularity of $\alpha$, that i think it's unnecessary. Do you agree?

Comment: $\alpha$ is a limit point of $C\cap\alpha$ which is not in $C\cap\alpha$, so $C\cap\alpha$ is not closed in $\kappa$ when $\alpha<\kappa$ is a limit ordinal and $C$ is unbounded in $\alpha$.

Comment: I see, by bad. Anyway, i can't see where Jech uses regularity of $\alpha$ to state that $C\cap \alpha$ is closed in $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, you're right: if $C$ is closed in $\kappa$ and $C\cap\alpha$ is unbounded in $\alpha$, then $C\cap\alpha$ is closed in $\alpha$.

For the second question, however, an additional assumption is indeed needed. For example, suppose $C$ is a club in $\omega_{\omega+1}$ (which is regular) with $C\cap \omega_\omega=\{\omega_i: i\in\omega\}$. Then $C'\cap\omega_\omega=\emptyset$.

Regularity (and uncountability) solves this problem, but is in fact not necessary: if $cf(\alpha)$ is uncountable and $C$ is a club in $\kappa$ which is unbounded in $\alpha$, then $C'\cap\alpha$ is again unbounded in $\alpha$. However, when we *iterate* the derivative we see a problem: $\alpha^{(cf(\alpha))}\cap \alpha$ is empty for all $\alpha$.

In fact, the following are equivalent:

- For all $C\subseteq\alpha$ club and all $\beta<\alpha$, $C^{(\beta)}$ is club in $\alpha$.
- $\alpha$ is uncountable and regular.

*Here "$X^{(\gamma)}$" denotes the $\gamma$th derivative of $X$, defined recursively as $X^{(0)}=X$, $X^{(\gamma+1)}=(X^{(\gamma)})'$, and $X^{(\lambda)}=\bigcap_{\gamma<\lambda}X^{(\gamma)}$ for limit $\lambda>0$.*